# How to implement a "dependency resolver" by "before" and "after"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to create a "dependency resolver" which relies on "before" and "after" other dependencies.

For example, if we have a requirement like:

- `A` should ***before*** `B,C` AND ***after*** `D,E`
- `D` should ***before*** `E`
- `E` should ***before*** `Z` AND ***after*** `Y`

How to order the dependencies correctly? (or just fails if it can't resolve)

Any ideas for this?

Comment: See [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Generate a graph that represents your constraints and then use any of the mentioned algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, does that apply to both "before" and "after" constrains? seems like it only applies to "depend on"(after).

Comment: @yaquawa needless to say, if ```E``` is after ```Y```, then ```Y``` is before ```E```. So topological sort would also handle that, if you're using a DAG